# selecting from a list in SQL and python

Tags: python, sqlite

I need help with the following scenario:

in my database file I have a table who looks something like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCMwJ.png]

I want to get a list of all the IDs that have `suppliers_id=(2,3)` (list of ids)

the problem is that I don't know which values are in the group (I'm getting the list in the function header from other SELECT function)

We were taught that we can use IN option that should get me the result I want but I cant getting it to work

my code (doesn't work for now):

```py
    def update(self, suppliers_id):
        c = self._conn.cursor()
        c.execute("""SELECT id FROM Vaccines WHERE supplier_id IN (?)""", [suppliers_id])
```

I'm getting `sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.` error

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select multiple values from table, you've to add it as a tuple without assigning it to a new memory address .

By assigning your variable as a list, you're assigning it to a new memory address which is insufficient way of using **Parameters Substitution**.

**Code Syntax**

```py
def update(self, suppliers_id):
    c = self._conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""SELECT id FROM Vaccines WHERE supplier_id IN (?)""", supplier_id, )   # by adding only comma, you're accessing the tuple, iteratively.
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass a tuple inside existing parenthesis in your sql query, this results to `IN ((some items))` which is not readable from sql. Try this instead (removed parenthesis and also change suppliers_id to tuple in case that it is a list):

```
def update(self, suppliers_id):
    c = self._conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""SELECT id FROM Vaccines WHERE supplier_id IN (?)""", [','.join(str(i) for i in suppliers_id)])
```

Comment: neither works for me, I get "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error"

Comment: Please add print(suppliers_id) before your sql statement and check what it's printed

Comment: It printed (2,)

Comment: I did some changes, please check again

Answer (score 0):

Two Options:

Either remove parenthesis from your sql query. For e.g.

```
def update(self, suppliers_id):
    c = self._conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""SELECT id FROM Vaccines WHERE supplier_id IN ?""", tuple(suppliers_id))
```

Or use format. For e.g.

```
def update(self, suppliers_id):
    c = self._conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""SELECT id FROM Vaccines WHERE supplier_id IN {}""".format(tuple(suppliers_id)))
```

Comment: Don't use `str.format`.  That way lies SQL Injection vulnerabilities.